# How do I import ActivityIndicatorIOS in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

Hello I am following a tutorial on Building an iOS app using JavaScript & ReactJS, I am having trouble trying to use ActivityIndicatorIOS and importing it into the file. here is how i declare a few things:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
   AppRegistry,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   View,
   ActivityIndicatorIOS
} from 'react-native';
```

Below is my class with the problem:

```
export default class SplashWalls extends Component {

  ....

  renderLoadingMessage() {
     return (
        <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
           <ActivityIndicatorIOS
             animating={true}
             color={'#fff'}
             size={'small'} 
             style={{margin: 15}} />
       <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>Contacting Unsplash</Text>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

When I run this project I get the below error:
[image: iOS App Error Displayed]

How do I successfully use ActivityIndicatorIOS? Thank you guys.

Comment: Import seems fine to me. Why do you think it is problem with `ActivityIndicatorIOS` import?

Comment: ActivityIndicatorIOS is deprecated. What is your react-native version?

Comment: @Prakashsharma Because when I remove ActivityIndicatorIOS from import it says "ActivityIndicatorIOS is not defined" and when i add it back i get the above error message.

Comment: @bennygenel my react-native -v is 2.0.1

Comment: thats react-native-cli version I believe. Whats the version number for react-native in your package.json file

Comment: @bennygenel I just checked it is: "react-native": "0.48.3"

Comment: Like the answers below you need to use `ActivityIndicator`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ActivityIndicator](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.48/docs/activityindicator.html#activityindicator) as `ActivityIndicatorIOS` is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

(I can't write comments yet, so I'm adding an answer)

I suppose you are using a recent version of React Native (could you provide what's in your package.json?)

If yes - try using `ActivityIndicator` ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html)) instead of `ActivityIndicatorIOS`.